# jQuery load div after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div called `news`. It contains some PHP code, mostly SQL queries. When I post some data using a form, I want my news div to be refreshed.

I've tried a few different things but I couldn't make it work.

If I add something like `success: $("#news").load(location.href + " #news")`, a whole new div is being created called **news** in the `news` div.

Here's my jQuery code.

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // process the form
    $('#new').submit(function (event) { // "new" is the id of my form

        // get the form data
        var formData = {
            'statustext': $("#statustext").val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url: '/modules/feed/process.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data: formData, // our data object
            dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode: true,
            success: alert(formData.statustext) // echoes the textarea input successfully, so I make sure that it works.
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
success: function(data) {
  // data from the post request
  $('#news').html(data);
}
```

If you data is html, otherwise you'd have to modify data to work

Comment: It didn't work. I'm new in jQuery, is there anything I should change in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load **page** or some **div** after using ajax, you must load page first with Jquery using .load.

```
<div id="newsid"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#newsid").load("newspage.php");
});
</script>
```

You can get your newspage.php using **Jquery .load**
after that, your ajax like here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // load first
    $("#newsid").load("newspage.php");

    // your ajax
    $('#new').submit(function (event) { // "new" is the id of my form
        // process the form
        $.ajax({
        // your code
        })

    //load again after submit ajax
    $("#newsid").load("newspage.php");

    });

});
```